# SharePoint 2010 search not working

Tags: search, search-results

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 project.
The problem I am having is the search function doesn't really work. Whatever I search for, the result is "We did not find any results for [the keywork I searched]". I have uploaded the documents and crawled the content source and the service is running on central admin. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the content sources are set up properly with correct url and schedules. Also check the crawl logs for errors.

Also check that your default content access account has permissions (web application read policy and read on user profile service app)

Comment: These places tend to be where most issues I have seen arise, the Crawl Log should always be the first place you want to go.  ULS is second, if you aren't getting anything in the Crawl Log.

Answer (score 0):

Is it for one library only, or for whole scope, portal? Check if the library is not removed from Search index (in CA) or if the setting in Library Advanced settings called "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" is not set to "No"

Answer (score 0):

What kind of documents did you upload? Make sure the file type extension is being crawled. It's found under Central Admin > Manage Service Applications > Search Service (your instance) > File Types (under crawling menu)